# Are react-native-ui-lib theme fontsize in dp or px?

Tags: react-native

I'm using 'react-native-ui-lib' and I want to create custom theme typography.  My codes look something like this

```
import { Colors, Typography } from 'react-native-ui-lib';

const typographies: Record<string, TextStyle> = {
  h1: { fontSize: 32, fontWeight: 'bold' },
  h2: { fontSize: 24, fontWeight: 'bold' },
}

Typography.loadTypographies(typographies);
```

I would like to know if the fontSize 32 and 24 are in dp or px.  If in dp, and the design given to me is in px, how do I convert the px to dp ?   Is this calculation correct ?

```
const dp = px => px / PixelRatio.getFontScale()
```

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**iOS:** Sizes are considered to be in "points" (not pixels). React Native handles the conversion from logical points to physical pixels based on the device's screen density (which is typically either 2x or 3x for modern iOS devices).

**Android:** Sizes are considered to be in "density-independent pixels" (dp or dip). React Native handles the conversion from dp to physical pixels based on the device's screen density.

***FOR YOUR CALCULATION SYNTEXT***

```
import { PixelRatio } from 'react-native';

const Dp = (px) => px / PixelRatio.get();

// Example usage:
const dpValue = Dp(24); // Convert 24px to dp
```